How to Compare the SLAM trajectory with Ground Truth
I am currently working on autonomous navigation and have successfully created a map using visual odometry and RTAB-Map SLAM. My next goal is to compare the generated map with the real-world environment. As part of this effort, I aim to plot the robot's trajectory created from visual odometry during the mapping process, utilizing GPS data.
I have set up an RTK GPS system following the instructions from " and configured the required parameters in the RTAB-Map launch file as shown below:
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" args="-d">
 <param name="ground_truth_frame_id" value="world"/>
 <param name="ground_truth_base_frame_id" value="base_footprint_gt"/>
 <arg name="gps_topic"                default="/ublox_gps/fix" /> 

Despite this setup, I am encountering an issue where ground truth values are not being published. A warning indicates that no transform is found from world to base_link_gt. I suspect this might be due to the absence of a TF broadcast associated with the GPS data.
I have also attempted to use the robot_localization package's navsat_transform_node to generate the required transform, but the problem persists.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Additionally, if you have any alternative suggestions or recommendations for comparing the mapping results, please let me know.
Anyone that can work on this can help me? Also, If you have any other suggestions for me or any recommendation for em to compare the mapping result.
